# For apps running on O devices, are there any changes to how Geofencing works?

Tags: android, android-location, android-geofence

There are limits placed on the collection of location in the background when running on "O" devices. Is Geofencing impacted by these changes?

Answer (score 0):

Apps that use geofences can specify a responsiveness value using [Geofence.Build#setNotificationResponsiveness](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#setNotificationResponsiveness(int)). Setting a large value (the API docs recommend 5 minutes) can save significant battery power. Apps running on O devices can set geofence responsiveness as before, but **when a small value is used, location services may adjust responsiveness to save power when needed**.